# How to search for strings not matching a regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

I want to search for strings that do not match a regex. 
I used:

```
grep -v -E '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' myfile.txt | wc -l
```

But I get:

```
$: command not found
```

I need to find the strings that do not comply to `digits.digits.digits.digits`. The `digits` length is 1-3.

Comment: Your issue is out there since the [`grep` command works fine](https://ideone.com/98lGB2). But you should use `-P` instead of `-E` since the pattern is a PCRE pattern.

Comment: I did. Not working. Same error: command not found.

Comment: Could it be a file permission issue?

Comment: Probably. But the only problem I see is the `\d` instead of `[0-9]` or `-E` instead of `-P`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/186808/every-command-fails-with-command-not-found-after-changing-bash-profile

Comment: This question has nothing to with your `grep` arguments, your shell simply cannot find a command named `grep` in your PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments provided by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) give insight into what the problem is. In order to find a solution to the problem, more information is to be sought. The output of the following would be helpful:

```
echo $PATH
```

This tells you which folders are checked when looking for commands. If the folder where grep is installed is not in that list, then the OS will not know where to find it.